# Webhooks and Sales/Service cloud

Tags: apex, servicecloud

I have a 3rd party system which supports webhooks. When something happens in this system it can be configured to post a payload to the destination of choice.
I would like to host some code in the salesforce eco system to take this payload and process it to update customer records.

I believe I can use Salesforce Apex to deliver this feature. I cant find any details around other approaches to hosting and executing code in the salesforce environment. Is this the only approach available?

Comment: Take a look at [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) for a high-level summary of options

Answer (score 2):

There is a superb new package `Streamscript` from the SFDC geniuses Matt & Neil (@matt-and-neil) that allows for web hook consumption by Flows

No Apex required, all config

- [Video (webhooks)](https://www.streamscript.com/assets/streamscript/webhooks-in-flow.mp4)
- [Doc](https://www.streamscript.com/)
- [Main web site with other tips on Streamscript](https://xbaf.com)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Apex is the only supported language that executes on the Salesforce platform proper. Keep in mind that you will also need:

- to set up a "Connected App" in Salesforce
- so you can go through an OAuth 2.0 flow
- to get an access token
- so you can actually make an API call into Salesforce

The one exception to that is to create a Salesforce "Site" and make it public, but you almost certainly don't want to make a public endpoint for this

Heroku (with Heroku connect) is an option, but it is an *expensive* option (*starting at* $4,000 per month). It would allow you to use your language of choice though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Apex Rest.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm